# How to inspect pseudo elements using Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11 developer tools

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I need write rules for pseudo elements specifically for Edge and IE, but It seems that both of these browsers are not showing ::after and ::before pseudo elements in their developer tools despite them being rendered on the page.

Is there way to edit them directly in browser, as it is possible on Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edge shows pseudo element styles on the given element, but after other (even inherited) styles....

So scroll down.